# What does the expression "way to go champ" mean?

Tags: meaning

I found this expression in the internet and I would like to know its meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Champ* is short for *champion*, the winner of a contest.  Literally taken, it's congratulatory --

> You've shown them that your performance is the **way to go** to demonstrate the qualities of a winner.

Check out this [greeting card](http://hammerpress.net/products/ec164), complete with winner's trophy and inscription.

But taken ironically, it means just the opposite, i.e,

> You're no champion and you've shown the **way to go** to defeat.

Here's a scene from *[A Scary Scene in a Scary Movie](https://books.google.com/books?id=tKx9WR8npzAC&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=%22way%20to%20go%20champ%22%20depressories&source=bl&ots=5OnOsDo0Qk&sig=QsseV1659rrN9vJ3zJ9PFi1lrs4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdh5P6gM7JAhWKTSYKHSs1DskQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%22way%20to%20go%20champ%22%20depressories&f=false)* by Matt Blackstone.  The narrator is trying to maintain his calm, fails to do so, and is mocked for his failure.

I unclench my teeth and tell my body not to do anything stupid.  It doesn't listen.  When I hold out my drinking glass for my mom to refill, I tell my fingers not to but they do it anyway: they relax, and let go.
   The glass clanks on the table as water seeps into the white tablecloth.
   **Way to go, champ**." Phil laughs.

There's no way to tell which without the context.